# Access azure key vault secret with application client secret

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault

Problem statement: retrieve and use a sensitive value (say a database connection string) stored in azure key vault programmatically in a web/console c# app.

I understand you can register an app in AAD and use its client id and client secret to generate an ad token programmatically which can be used to call/access azure key vault secrets.

My confusion is that the client secret itself is a sensitive ‘password’ which you would want to store in the key vault. Once someone knows the client secret they can access all secrets in the key vault. So how does it make sense to create a new secret (client secret) to store and access the original secret? (Can someone pls explain the logic behind this? Thanks!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/key-vault/general/secure-your-key-vault

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the problem of *bootstrapping*.
How do you get access to the secret store without using a secret?

If you run your app in Azure, the answer is pretty simple.
Use [Managed identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview).

If not running in Azure, an interactive app can access Key Vault on behalf of the current user.
This does require that the user has access to the Key Vault secrets.

Another approach would be to use a certificate instead of a client secret.

Comment: Thanks. My app is a Windows application running locally on the user's computer. Can you elaborate a bit what you mean 'an interactive app' is it some kind of user impersonation? Appreciate if you have any links for both option#2 and #3.

Comment: Okay, so when it is a "public client app", an app that runs on a user's device, you can't authenticate the app. You can only authenticate the user. Also note that the Key Vault data would be accessible to the user using the app, which is why it would make sense to access the Key Vault as them. If they already have access to those secrets, then there is no issue with them being accessible to them here as well. There is a .NET sample app here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-net.

Comment: As @juunas said, a client certificate would be a good approach.  Create a client certificate using Key Vault (self-signed is fine).  Associate the certificate with the service principal (registered application) which allows it to log in using that certificate.  You can then install the certificate on the local machine and allow the code to send the cert as it's login method.

Comment: I marked your response as the answer. Finally can you clarify - I understand there are these workarounds, then in what scenarios are the client/client secret approach useful since they seem to have the bootstrapping problem?

Comment: That approach can work in cases where you can't use Managed Identities and you are running the app in an environment that you trust, like a back-end server application or a scheduled job running on a server. Key Vault gives you a centralized configuration store at least in that case. It isn't quite as secure as it could be, but it can be okay as long as that secret remains a secret.

Answer (score 1):

If you host your app on Azure, you can use managed identities to perform authentication between services.
Once the Azure configuration is done, you need to add the following in your app: it only need to store the Azure KeyVault URI - as env variable would be better.

The following code uses Azure KeyVault with the AppConfiguration, so the local `appsettings.json` file is empty:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, configBuilder) =>
            {
                if (hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment()) return;

                AddAzureKeyVault(configBuilder);

                var configRoot = configBuilder.Build();
                AddAzureAppConfiguration(configBuilder, configRoot);
            });

        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
    });

private static void AddAzureKeyVault(IConfigurationBuilder configBuilder)
{
    var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
    var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
    var keyVaultName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KEY_VAULT_NAME");

    configBuilder.AddAzureKeyVault(
        $"https://{keyVaultName}.vault.azure.net/",
        keyVaultClient,
        new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());
}

private static void AddAzureAppConfiguration(IConfigurationBuilder configBuilder, IConfigurationRoot configRoot)
{
    var appConfigName = configRoot["AppConfiguration-Name"];
    configBuilder.AddAzureAppConfiguration(appConfigName);
}
```