# Should the Azure Key Vault URL be hidden?

Tags: c#, azure, security, azure-keyvault

In the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-net) they store part of the name for the Azure Key Vault as an Environment variable, and then use it like this:

```
string keyVaultName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KEY_VAULT_NAME");
var kvUri = "https://" + keyVaultName + ".vault.azure.net";

var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());
```

I get how it works, but I cannot figure out *why* they are doing it this way?

1. I don't get why the URL for the vault needs to be hidden, since you cannot enter it unless it is explicitly configured in *Access Policies*. You simply get a 403 Forbidden (see screenshot).
2. Even if it were a secret, why not use the `appconfig.json` file? Isn't that what you usually use - and why they split it in a release and Development (`appsettings.Development.json`) version?

[image: Attempt to access key vault without permission]

Comment: If an attacker gets on your server and is able to read environment variables, or the file on disk if you store in with appsettings.json, then that's one less hurtle for them to get over because they know _where_ your secrets are stored.

Comment: As you already mentioned it's not about keeping it a secret. The reason why they use an environment is mostly just convenience. As you mentioned an `appconfig` or `appsettings` would also work, but for a short console app demo running on various platforms this is as easy as it gets.

Comment: Just because somebody doesn't have your house key doesn't mean it's a good idea to tell random strangers your full home address.

Comment: @gunr2171, is it that difficult for an attacker to know that KeyVaultName needs a suffix of .vault.azure.net and prefix of https ?! are we talking about people here or machine that scrap files for URLs to try ?!

Answer (score 1):

> I don't get why the URL for the vault needs to be hidden, since you
> cannot enter it unless it is explicitly configured in Access Policies.

Basically, keyvault uris are needed to be hidden because they may attract unneccessary attention of bruteforce attackers and hackers and they may try to get in your keyvault using the uri which has been shared in public . Incase access to the keyvault is not correctly configured, It might be vulnerable to misuse and as the  *keyvault name which mentioned in the  uri which is supposed to be private thus it is hidden* .

> Even if it were a secret, why not use the appconfig.json file? Isn't
> that what you usually use - and why they split it in a release and
> Development (appsettings.Development.json) version.

You can normally use the secrets stored in keyvault in `appsettings.json` file by calling the access key to that secret and providing the correct permissions for the usage of that secret in key vault.
When running the application the appsettings.json file split into two parts where secrets are loaded in development and values are in production due to which there are two versions of `appsettings.json` file one for production and one for release version.

For more information please refer the below links:

***SO THREAD*** :- [***Access azure key vault secret with application client secret***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65696960/access-azure-key-vault-secret-with-application-client-secret?rq=1)

***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION:-*** [***Azure Key Vault configuration provider in ASP.NET Core***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-6.0)